# Huge process called "swift" in the activity monitor, appears after installing Xcode 11.0

Tags: macos, mac, memory, xcode

After installing Xcode 11.0, a strange processes keep showing up in the activity monitor, causing the system to freeze sometimes, and crash (shutdown) other times, these processes are called "swift", and the strange part it takes memory space larger than the actual memory installed on the device.

Device Info : Mac Book Pro mid 2015, MAC OS 10.15

[image: strange swift processes screen shoot]

[image: Extremely large swift processes screen shoot]

Comment: Swift is part of Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/swift/ I don't use it so idk how many instances are supposed to run, or what size they should be.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks,  but I know swift as a programming language, and I believe that this processes referring to code compilation, but why it is so large and kill the whole operating system, and how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: More data, I've had several crashes with Xcode 11 that seem to be related to Swift code-completion (they usually happen when I'm typing to fast for the completion to keep up), and on the last one I noticed a couple of 'swift' processes were jammed up with huge memory and ongoing CPU consumption.